# SQL Statement - Java

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, jdbc

I've been trying to come up with a couple of SQL statements on how to get this right but no luck. I've tried `between`, `>= and =<`. Basically, the SQL statement that I've used is working but to an extent only.

My code works like this: the user will choose a date range (from date and to date) and the program will retrieve and show the data it has within those range. Like I said, it works but it also shows the days from the other months when what I want to show is just those particular days that the user picked. eg. from July 1, 2016 to July 5, 2016. What's happening is any month of the year that has those dates will show as well which makes that particular method a bit useless.

Any help or any explanation why is this so would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
stringFromDate = sdf.format(fromDate.getDate());

stringToDate = sdf.format(toDate.getDate());

String query = "Select * from tblSavings where date between '" + stringFromDate+ "' and '" + stringToDate+"'";

try{ 

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    tblList.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Most likely the format of `stringFromDate` and `stringToDate` are incorrect, and this is why the query is not working as you expect.  Update and show us the actual raw query being executed.  Also, what version of SQL is being used?

Comment: @marc_s I'm looking at the link you gave me right now. Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm using SQLite. Thanks!

What I don't get is why is it getting the days from the other months. I really thought it was working but then this. I'm a bit moronic when it comes to terminologies and would like to give you what you asked but I'm afraid you jargoned the hell out of me. Thanks still. :)

Comment: Show us the literal values of `stringFromDate` and `stringToDate`.

Comment: As marc_s said: use a prepared Statement and use `setDate()` to pass the actual date value after parsing the user input (this is however a somewhat unreliable with SQLite as it doesn't have a real `DATE` data type)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if the user chose July 1, 2016 to July 4, 2016 it will come up as 01/Jul/2016 and 04/July/2016

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to re-invent the wheel here. `PreparedStatement`s were created exactly for this usecase - setting variable values in a predefined structure. In your case, with the [`setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-) method. From the context I'm guessing your `fromDate` and `toDate` variables are [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instances, so you'll have to convert them to [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)s

```
java.sql.Date fromDateToBind = new java.sql.Date(fromDate);
java.sql.Date toDateToBind = new java.sql.Date(toDate);

String query = "Select * from tblSavings where date between ? and ?";

try{ 
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pstmt.setDate(1, fromDateToBind);
    pstmt.setDate(2, toDateToBind);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

    // use the results...
} // etc...
```

Comment: I've used what Tim suggested and it worked. I'll keep this in mind as well and will try on the next project I'm gonna make. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to get a string which is in proper format to be used as a date in SQLite, the proper format being `yyyy-MM-dd`:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String stringFromDate = dateFormat.format(fromDate.getDate());
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks a lot!